# Configure NGINX to redirect '/' location to static site hosted on S3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, server

I have a VueJS web application and a landing page that are separate. I have an NGINX config that handles my app, and I also want it to re-direct to my S3 static site when I access "/" location block. How can I get this configured? Is this the correct approach?

Here is my static site on S3: https://greysonlandingpage.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/index.html

Here is my current NGINX configuration:

```
server {
  listen $PORT;
  index index.html index.html;

  location / {
    #I need this to redirect to static hosted site
  }

  location /vuejsApp {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/(?:ping) {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5050;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

P.S. I'm hosting static site on S3 because for some odd reason deploying my app in one docker to Heroku is causing issues on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
location / {
     try_files $uri.html /path_to_the_static_hosted_site/index.html =404;
    }
```

**Do not forget:**

- The path_to_the_static.... should be relative of the root of your project. Eg. If your static_file is inside public/static/index.html and the root in you nginx config is /home/usr/sitename.xyz/public, the path will be /static/index.html
- On vue, you should set inside the vue.config.js file, the publicPath, to tell Babel where to look for files to dynamic import: eg.

  `module.exports = { publicPath: '/static/dist'...`